# How to get lastLogonTimestamp from all DCs for specific users

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

I'm trying to make  a script  for  query all  the users  from specific users  in my  domain and  get the last "lastLogonTimestamp" from each  user , and  export the  result  to  a csv  file . eg : "SOL*" for users beginning SOL
I obtain the results for most users   for "last logon date"  the date 31/12/1600 06:00:00 p.m but  i  dont  know why  for some users get the correct date and for other for users the date of the year  1600, regardless if they are in the same OU or not.

```
Get-ADDomainController -filter * | 
% {Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True' -and SamAccountName -like 'SOL*'" -server $_.name -Properties         Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,LastLogon,Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled -SearchBase "OU=users,DC=contoso,DC=local" | 
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,@{N='Last‌​Logon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}},Manager,Title,Department,Organizatio‌​n,Enabled}|
Group samaccountname |
ForEach{$_.Group | Sort LastLogon -Descending | Select -First 1} |
Export-Csv "C:\export\AD_Export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that user has **never logon using that particular DC**.

For example, an employee in US will probably never contact the Europe DC during logon. In this case the lastlogon on Europe DC will be "31/12/1600 06:00:00 p.m" (min value of lastlogon is January 1, 1601 (UTC), the time you saw is "time-zoned").

One more thing, **lastLogonTimestamp** and **lastLogon** are 2 different attributes.
**lastLogon** record the exact logon time but is not replicated among DC.
**lastLogonTimestamp** is replicated, but it is only an approximation.
(by default it can be <= 14 days earlier than actual value, only useful for finding idle account...)

In your case, you are actually talking about **lastLogon**.